# Java's AWT or Swing for GUI construction?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I need to compose a fairly simple GUI for a server monitoring process.  It will have a few tabs which lead to a log tailing, counts of resources, and a start and top control.  Nothing fancy here.  Which Java framework, AWT or Swing, makes more sense for something this simple.

Answer (score 16):

Swing is the way to go.  It's a cleaner programming interface, and looks better.

Comment: It's also lighter on resources because of how it was designed.

Answer (score 3):

Use Swing or [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), since AWT has no tabs built in.

Starting with [Java 6 Update 10](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/java6u10/), Swing got an entirely new look and feel, the 'Nimbus Look and Feel'. It looks great and is really fast because it uses vector graphics.

Comment: Ugh, ANOTHER new default look for Swing?  Granted, the 1.4 (purple) look was ugly, but the 1.5 look wasn't that bad, nor was the 6 look.

Answer (score 2):

Swing is your best choice if you're stuck choosing between Swing and AWT.

If you have the flexibility, I would at least consider [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/).  It's faster, matches the platform look and feel, and seems to have fewer porting hurdles and regression problems from release to release.  There is a small hurdle in setting up your first project (getting the right jars and such), but other than that, it's no more difficult to work in.

Comment: SWT is certainly nice, but it is an extra native library dependency compared to Swing which is available by default to all Java implementations. Unless you specifically need something that SWT provides, I would normally recommend Swing simply for portability / maintenance reasons. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

AWT was the first Java GUI framework, it had a lot of flaws and was abandoned in favor of Swing. The main reason it is still in the JDK is for backwards compatibility and because some classes are re-used by Swing.

The future however (even for the desktop) could be [JavaFX](http://www.sun.com/software/javafx/).

Answer (score 1):

if you are planning to move your gui onto multiple platforms, then go with AWT.  Otherwise, Swing gives you a much broader set of components to work with.

Comment: I guess by "multiple platforms" you mean non-desktop platforms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a better looking GUI, you can have a look at substance look and feel package in this address: https://substance.dev.java.net/see.html

Comment: True, but not really answering the question.